# Как убрать значения осей на графике?

Tags: python, matplotlib

никак не могу избавиться от значения осей на графике. Мне нужная только картинка графика.сохранять изображение умею, не могу убрать значения и сменить весь фон на черный.

```
from numpy import genfromtxt
import mpl_finance
window_size=60

DATA_FOLDER = 'C:\\DataSet'
data_buy = genfromtxt(DATA_FOLDER+'/BASE.csv', encoding='utf-16', delimiter='\t' ,dtype=str)

data_buy = np.flipud(data_buy)

def generateFXTimeS():
    for i in range(20):
        direction = 'ok'
        open = []
        high = []
        low = []
        close = []
        volume = []
        open2 = []
        high2 = []
        low2 = []
        close2 = []
        volume2 = []
        date = []
        start=i*window_size
        
        for start in range(start,start+window_size,1):
            open.append(float(data_buy[start][1]))
            high.append(float(data_buy[start][2]))
            low.append(float(data_buy[start][3]))
            close.append(float(data_buy[start][4]))
            volume.append(float(data_buy[start][5]))
            open2.append(float(data_buy[start][6]))
            high2.append(float(data_buy[start][7]))
            low2.append(float(data_buy[start][8]))
            close2.append(float(data_buy[start][9]))
            volume2.append(float(data_buy[start][10]))
            date.append(data_buy[start][0])
            

        sma = convolve_sma(close,9)
        smb = list(sma)
        diff = sma[-1] - sma[-2]
        for x in range(len(close)-len(smb)):
            smb.append(smb[-1]+diff)
            
        sma2 = convolve_sma(close, 21)
        smb2 = list(sma2)
        diff = sma2[-1] - sma2[-2]
        for x in range(len(close)-len(smb2)):
            smb2.append(smb2[-1]+diff)
            
        sma3 = convolve_sma(close, 31)
        smb3 = list(sma3)
        diff = sma3[-1] - sma3[-2]
        for x in range(len(close)-len(smb3)):
            smb3.append(smb3[-1]+diff)
            
        fig = plt.figure(figsize=(3, 3), dpi=50, facecolor='w', edgecolor='k')
        fig.set_facecolor("Black")
        plt.axis('off')
        fig.patch.set_visible(False)
        #dx = fig.add_subplot(111)
        dx=fig.add_subplot(111, label="1")
        dx2=fig.add_subplot(111, label="2", frame_on=False)
        dx3=fig.add_subplot(111, label="3", frame_on=False)
        dx4=fig.add_subplot(111, label="4", frame_on=False)
        dx5=fig.add_subplot(111, label="5", frame_on=False)
        mpl_finance.candlestick2_ochl(dx,open, close, high, low, width=1.5, colorup='r', colordown='g', alpha=0.5)
        mpl_finance.candlestick2_ochl(dx2,open2, close2, high2, low2, width=1.5, colorup='gray', colordown='gray', alpha=0.5)
        
        plt.autoscale()
        dx3.plot(smb, color="blue", linewidth=5, alpha=0.5)
        dx4.plot(smb2, color="red", linewidth=5, alpha=0.5)
        dx5.plot(smb3, color="orange", linewidth=5, alpha=0.5)
        plt.axis('off')
        
        #plt.savefig( os.path.join(train_output_dir,str(direction) +'_{}.jpg'.format(i+i)),bbox_inches='tight')
        plt.show()

        open.clear()
        close.clear()
        volume.clear()
        high.clear()
        low.clear()
        plt.cla()
        plt.clf()
        plt.close(fig)

if __name__ == '__main__': generateFXTimeS()
```

Answer (score 1):

Чтобы скрыть отметки у графика, укажите пустой список.

```
plt.xticks([])
plt.yticks([])
```

Comment: указываю перед plt.show() не помогает(

Answer (score 0):

```py
plt.get_xaxis().set_visible(False)
plt.get_yaxis().set_visible(False)
```

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]